# MVC:Why controller object is being created every time when we hit on an action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Okay I have a home controller and an action index in it.My view retrieves the value from the demo function in home controller.Each time I hit on the button(in index view) ,it creates the homecontroller object and id is being initialized as 1.So,my second condition in the demo function is not executing.However,if I make the id variable as static,it works.So,why on the click of button,controller object is being created everytime.Why there is a need to create different object each time when we can perform similar action on a specific object?

Home Controller:

```
public class homeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public int id = 1;
        public string demo() 
        {
            if (id == 1)
            {
                id++;
                return "hello";
            }
            id--;
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Index View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('#b1').click(function () {
            var URL = "/home/demo";
            $.get(URL, function (data) {
                $("#t1").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>


<div>
<p id="t1"></p>
<input id="b1" type="button" value="button1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of design.

On `ASP.NET MVC`,  the lifecycle is as follows:

HTTP Request --> Routing to the MVC Handler --> Controller creation --> 
Action method invocation --> Result (View) execution --> back to client.

Check out the [Lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application), the `PDF` document there is very informative.

Specifically on your example, the `$.get` request generates a new HTTP Request, you might want to send the Id or to keep it in a place out of the controller.